# Angular how to set data in form array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I'm using angular 8. In this I have an api like

```
{

    "no": "s01",
    "id": 1,
    "details_id": {
        "install": "Y"
        "unitprice": "100.000000000000000",
        "weight": "1.000000000000000"
        },
        "qty": 1,
        "remarks": "ok" 
}
```

I have to patch data in this format below using angular

```
{
 
  "Header_img": null,
  "details": [
    {
      "install": "",
      "remarks":""
      "del_details": [
        {
          "qty": "",
          "unitprice":"",
          "weight": ""
          
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.Form = this.fb.group({
      Header_img: [],
      podetails: this.fb.array([this.addpodetailsGroup()])
    });
  }

  addpodetailsGroup() {
    let group=  new FormGroup({
      install: new FormControl(''),
      d_details: this.fb.array([
        this.d_detailsGroup()
      ])
    }
  )
return group}

  d_detailsGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      qty: new FormControl(''), 
      "unitprice": new FormControl(''), 
      "weight": new FormControl(''), 
    });
  }
```

patch function

```
getdDetails(){
    let id = this.iddata
    this.dataService.getdetails(id)
    .subscribe((results) => {
      let datas = results["data"];
      this.dList = datas
    })
  }
  
getdetailsForQuantity(data){
  let id = data.id 
  console.log('id value data getdetailsForQuantity',id)
this.dataService.getdetailsfor(id)
  .subscribe((result: any)  => {
     this.install = result.details_id.installationrequired
     this.unitprice = result.details_id.unitprice
    this.form.patchValue({
         
         details:[{
              install: this.install
             d_details: this.unitprice
          }]

    })


})

}
```

how to patch the data in form array?. Using reactive forms how to patch data in which the data from the backend is not in exact format to send the data to submit, but I have to patch and pass the data in nested array format.

Answer (score -1):

**Find the solution below:**

You have to create you formGroup for the FormArray respective with the response length.

if response like,

```
{
  "Header_img": null,
  "details": [
    {
      "install": "",
      "remarks":""
      "del_details": [
        {
          "qty": "",
          "unitprice":"",
          "weight": ""
        },
        {
          "qty": "",
          "unitprice":"",
          "weight": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And my form is like below

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    install: '',
    remarks: '',
    del_details: new FormArray()
});

addControltoFormArray() {
     return this.fb.group({
         qty: '',
         unitprice: '',
         weight: ''
     });
}
```

And patch the form like below,

```
getdetailsForQuantity(data){
    let id = data.id; 
    console.log('id value data getdetailsForQuantity',id);
    this.dataService.getdetailsfor(id)
    .subscribe((result: any)  => {
         this.form.patch({
             install: result.details.install,
             remarks: result.details.remarks
         });
         let control = this.form.get('del_details') as FormArray;
         result.details.del_details.forEach((obj:any,index:any) => {
              control.push(this.addControltoFormArray());
              control.controls(index).patch({
                  qty: obj:qty,
                  unitprice: obj.unitprice,
                  weight: obj.weight
              });
         });
         console.log(this.form.value);
    });
}
```

I think this will help you...

Comment: If you need to patch array to value FormArray then u need to first create the formGroup dynamically when u getted respective to your api value